# Get the network name (SSID) in node-webkit?

Tags: node.js, network-programming, operating-system, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm developing a node.js application which is running inside a node-webkit container. I would like to get some information about the network (SSID) the client is currently connected to.

I already had a look at the Node os API (http://nodejs.org/api/os.html) and the output of the function `os.networkInterfaces()`. It's however just returning the network interfaces and doesn't give me the network names.

Is is possible to retrieve this kind of information and if so, how would I do that?

**UPDATE**: What I actually want to do is to check if this user already connected to this particular network with his machine before. I don't really care about the name (SSID), what I need is a way to identify the local network.

Comment: Did you try something like `var id  = require('child_process').exec('iwgetid')` (on linux of course)

Comment: @adeneo No I didn't try that so far. I was hoping to user something which works cross OS because the app will mainly be used on Mac and Windows.